# re-establish relationship link

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

So I had an issue/problem that is detailed here ([Sorting error in one field of Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44269792/sorting-error-in-one-field-of-report])), which leads to my current problem.

I have two tables (Owners and Boats) that were once joined in a relationship via the fields Boat_Owner – (number field on Boat Table) and Owner_ID - (Primary Key  autonumber on Owner Table).   Due to a problem the data type in the number field on Boat Table has been changed from number to short text.

So now the relationship is no longer working and as a result I’m getting the ‘data type mismatch’ error.

Both tables are intact with table Boat having 355 unique entries and table Owner having 295 unique entries, some owners own more than one boat.  The autonumber ID’s are still intact in both tables so for example I know that Boat 401 finds its ownership with Owner 33.  Unfortunately I cannot figure out how to re-establish the table relationships due to the aforementioned field data type issue.

I’m thinking I can run an append query to re-establish the owner_ID field into the Boat table as a number field.

From this point I’m going to manually enter all of the owner_ID.  Far from desirable as there are 295 of them.   I have been using excel to match the two tables on one spreadsheet but I’m open to suggestions if someone has a better procedure.

If it does work my thought is I could then re-establish the relationship between the two tables.

I’m not sure if I am going about this the best way, or even if this is the correct way to go about this.

If anyone has input I’m open to suggestions.  I’ll post my progress if there is some.

Comment: Why can't you change `Boat_Owner` back to number?

Comment: That is a good question and I don't have an answer for you.  It is not for lack of trying, but whenever I did try the field would come up blank on every row leaving me back to manually filling in each field.

Comment: Well, what exactly *does* the current text column contain?

Comment: Right now the column contains the names in text form.  I believe prior to this the autonumber ID was there except it was represented as the individuals name.  I should add, if I try to change the data type on the design side to number I get the warning that this will clear all the fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Right now the column contains the names in text form.

Then you can do the following:

Create a new column in `Boats`: `Owner_ID` Number, Long integer.

Then fill this column with an UPDATE query from a join via the owner names:

```
UPDATE Boats INNER JOIN Owners
  ON Boats.Boat_Owner = Owners.Owner_Name
SET Boats.Owner_ID = Owners.Owner_ID
```

If there are duplicate names (John Smith), there will be wrong assignments and you'll have to correct these manually.

When all Owner_ID's are assigned correctly, you can create a new 1:n relationship, now from `Owners.Owner_ID` to `Boats.Owner_ID`.

Afterwards you should delete the `Boats.Boat_Owner` column, it is now useless.

Comment: I'll try this and let you know.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: Thanks again for the input.  I would say the solution worked very well, but I am still encountering an issue with new inputs. When I use the form to input information such as the owners name it shows up as text on the form. When I look at the table the text has converted to the number ID that it is assigned. Perhaps somewhat trivial, but it does make the tables look odd in that newer entries are numbers instead of the text. I suspect this might have to do with the relationship that is set up between the tables.  Any suggestions how to ensure that the tables show as text instead of the number?